# Dataset with time column is being read through R as decimal numbers

Tags: r

Attached are pictures showing the time column in [excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoNlp.png) and in [R after preliminary loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDQUd.png). I have been digging through forums as to how I could change the format to retain the HH:mm:ss structure and haven't had luck with "(as.)chron", "as.date", nor "format" [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mak26.png). Let me know if you have any tips, I am just starting with R.

```
times <- as.character(FeData_18[, 3])
time1 <- as.chron(times, format=c('h:m:s'))
time2 <- format(FeData_18[, 3], format=c('h:m:s'))
time <- chron(times, format=c('h:m:s')
```

where FeData[, 3] is the time column.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the column as `character` class. Whatever function you're using to read the data into R should have an argument that will let you specify column classes.

Comment: Writing in col_type="character" (on line 5 in 'as shown' link) for the third column (time) gives an error saying this it's illegal. If I try "text" it returns the same decimal numbers. If I try "date" it yields the time format I want but adds random dates (yyyy-MM-dd) and says there are 50+ warnings.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you had posted pictures of your `read_excel` code - posting code as text is better.

Comment: Since when you read it in as text you get decimals, then it probably means that's how Excel is storing it, and the only way R can access it. Probably it's fractions of a day. Looking at `?chron`, the `format` arg is for specifying the **input** format, not the output.

Comment: I think if you use `chron(times. = times)` you'll be fine. The first arg of `chron` defaults to `dates.`, but you don't have dates, just times, so you need to tell `chron` that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments, George Thomas! None of it really worked though changing the excel file to a csv did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the time is being saved in excel as a percentage of a day (between 0 and 1). For example 0.4375 corresponds to 10:30:00. This can be calculated as follows:

0.4375 * 24 * 3600 seconds from midnight = 37800 seconds = 10 hrs 30 minutes.

We can do this in R in the following way:

```
tm1.lt <- as.POSIXlt("2022-10-13")
tm1.lt
dec <- 0.4375
tm1.lt <- tm1.lt + (dec*24*3600)
tm1.lt
strftime(tm1.lt,"%H:%M:%S")
```

Output:

```
> tm1.lt <- as.POSIXlt("2022-10-13")
> tm1.lt
[1] "2022-10-13 IST"
> dec <- 0.4375
> tm1.lt <- tm1.lt + (dec*24*3600)
> tm1.lt
[1] "2022-10-13 10:30:00 IST"
> strftime(tm1.lt,"%H:%M:%S")
[1] "10:30:00"
```